# How to set a value to var in use() method php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

It seems that I can only read the value from a variable I pass in `use($ids)` but I can't update the value. How can I change the value?

here is my code

```
public function show(LPJ $lpj){
   $ids = [];
   $lpj->request->each(function ($item, $key) use ($ids) {
        if ($item->is_submitted) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!$item->form) {
            return true;
        }

        $form = json_decode($item->form, true);
        $is_submitted = false;

        foreach ($form as $value) {
            if (!$value['required']) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($value['value'] === null) {
                $is_submitted = false;
                break;
            }
            $is_submitted = true;
        }
        if ($is_submitted) {
            $request_lpj = RequestLPJ::find($item->id);
            $request_lpj->is_submitted = true;
            $request_lpj->save();

            // here I tried to update the $ids
            $ids[] = $key;

        }
    });
}
```

And it always return an empty array.
How can I pass value to the parent variable?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Passing by Reference  `use (&$ids)`

```
$ids = [];
   $lpj->request->each(function ($item, $key) use (&$ids) {
        if ($item->is_submitted) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!$item->form) {
            return true;
        }

        $form = json_decode($item->form, true);
        $is_submitted = false;

        foreach ($form as $value) {
            if (!$value['required']) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($value['value'] === null) {
                $is_submitted = false;
                break;
            }
            $is_submitted = true;
        }
        if ($is_submitted) {
            $request_lpj = RequestLPJ::find($item->id);
            $request_lpj->is_submitted = true;
            $request_lpj->save();

            // here I tried to update the $ids
            $ids[] = $key;

        }
    });
```